# custom hook for storing react hook refs to deal with stale closure problem

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a reusable hook that solves the problem of the stale closure problem that is outlined in this [blog post](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/).

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-wozniak-1jjtz) that shows the problem of the stale closure in action:

```
const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let id = setInterval(() => {
      callback();
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);
};


const App: React.FC = () => {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useInterval(() => setCount(count + 1), 1000);

  return <h1>{count}</h1>;
};
```

Basically `count` is frozen at 0 when the closure is created meaning `0` is added to `1` continually in the `setInterval`.

The blog post solves this by introducing a mutable ref to store the callback in:

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useInterval(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, 1000);

  return <h1>{count}</h1>;
}

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }

    let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [delay]);
}
```

The `useEffect` never gets re-executed because the callback is not in the `useEffect` dependency array with the `setInteval`.

I've seen some libraries using a hook like the `useStoreCallback` below but the linter still complains that the `savedCallback` variable below needs to be added to the dependency array.

Is this actually better?

```
type UnknownResult = unknown;
type UnknownArgs = any[];

function useStoreCallback<R = UnknownResult, Args extends any[] = UnknownArgs>(
  fn: (...args: Args) => R
) {
  const ref = React.useRef(fn);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = fn;
  });

  return React.useCallback<typeof fn>(
    (...args) => ref.current.apply(void 0, args),
    []
  );
}

function useInterval<R = UnknownResult, Args extends any[] = UnknownArgs>(
  callback: (...args: UnknownArgs) => R,
  delay: number
) {
  const savedCallback = useStoreCallback(callback);

  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback();
    }

    let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [delay, savedCallback]);
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useInterval(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, 1000);

  return <h1>{count}</h1>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [functional `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) and rid off the closure.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useInterval(() => setCount(c => c + 1), 1000);

  return <h1>{count}</h1>;
};
```

[image: Edit serene-sunset-60wye]

Comment: that works in a simple example but in something f more complicated it fails apart.  i wanted to keep my example simple

Comment: Show us the "more complicated", this question is too abstract and too broad anyway

Comment: On saying "too broad" I mean - asking about **solving "the stale closure problem"**, it depends on the context and what you trying to achieve.

Comment: This should be the answer regardless of complexity? But yeah, show the more complicated answer if that's what your question really pertains to.